# Get initial height/width of canvas in <ion-content>

Tags: typescript, dom, ionic4, angular8

I have a IONIC4/Angular8 setup with a header and splitpane-Menu.
Then I load BabylonJS engine into the View-Child of the `#canvas` inside `<ion-content>`.

For that reason I need to set the height and width of the canvas correctly.
Using `window.innerHeight`/`window.innerWidth` will always include the menu and the header.

I have a working window-resize Eventlistener but the first initial BabylonJS view always gets distorted.

My question is, how can i dynamically get the width and height of just the canvas?
`canvas.nativeElement.clientHeight` was my assumption - but i always received a 0.

Any hints?

**UPDATE**

I tried the suggested solution of answer of @rtpHarry - here are my results:

[image: You can see my content canvas at (1) and my menu at (2). If you look at the outputs in the console (3) is showing the correct height of the canvas but the width still includes the menu. This is further highlighted if you compare (3) to (4) where i outputted the window.innerwidth. The header gets deducted but the menu does not.]
You can see my content canvas at (1) and my menu at (2). If you look at the outputs in the console (3) is showing the correct height of the canvas but the width still includes the menu. This is further highlighted if you compare (3) to (4) where i outputted the window.innerwidth. The header gets deducted but the menu does not.

These is the stuff i use...
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The trick you're looking for is to find the size of the ion-content, which can be done using the following:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { IonContent } from '@ionic/angular';

export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(IonContent, { static: true }) private content: IonContent;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.content.getScrollElement().then(scrollElement => {
      console.log("clientHeight: ", scrollElement.clientHeight);
      console.log("clientWidth: ", scrollElement.clientWidth);
      console.log("scrollHeight: ", scrollElement.scrollHeight);
      console.log("scrollWidth: ", scrollElement.scrollWidth);
    });
  }
}
```

Client width and height are your width and height of the ion-content.

If the content was longer than the current page and you had scrollbars, the scroll width and height would be set to those values.

This is the output I'm getting, which I confirmed with devtools:

[image]

You can't make `ngOnInit` async but depending on where you are doing this you could do an async version like:

```
  async someOtherFunction() {
    const scrollElement = await this.content.getScrollElement();
    console.log("clientHeight: ", scrollElement.clientHeight);
    console.log("clientWidth: ", scrollElement.clientWidth);
    console.log("scrollHeight: ", scrollElement.scrollHeight);
    console.log("scrollWidth: ", scrollElement.scrollWidth);
  }
```

## Update

I tested it with a dashboard I'm building at the moment and it does give me the correct ion-content's dimensions:

[image]

I added a button (1) and it outputs (2) and checking it against the splitpane (3) it matches up apart from some sub-pixel rounding.

Do you have other stuff on the page that is overflowing and affecting it? Because I actually was seeing some discrepancy at first with an `ng-datatable` component on there, but when I commented it out and just left the basics the numbers matched up.

Comment: Thank you @rtpHarry. This partly solves my issue. It gives me the correct height. And I am able to get the correct width if my `<ion-menu>` is hidden in the hamburger-menu. But if the `<ion-menu>` is shown in full-screen the width is not correct. It includes the `<ion-menu>`-width. Do you know a way to get the width of the `<ion-menu>` dynamically? If yes I can easily subtract it from the content-menu. That would solve my issue.

Comment: Great, please consider upvoting if it helped. I will setup a demo app when I get into the office and figure this out. The technique can be applied to any component though, I think, so my plan would be to do an IonMenu version of `@ViewChild(IonContent, null) private content: IonContent;` and then apply the same techniques to get dimensions.

Comment: Thanks. Looking forward to your demo app! I gave you an upvote.

Comment: what is that `poweredBy` that I can see in the markup? I think thats whats sitting between the discrepancy of your two widths. A div doesn't work as a block level item, it floats or flex's into a row, not sure what exactly, but it doesn't act like normal html as you might expect.

Comment: That `poweredBy` is just a div containing a text. But it does not influence the result. I tried it without it - with the same result. Do you know a way to get the dynamically get the width of a `<ion-menu>` which is part of a `<ion-split-pane>`. I tried the `@ViewChild` approach, but was not able to find the width. Any further hints?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (full code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axemx8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)):

```
@ViewChild('canvasElement', {static: false}) canvasElement: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
     var context = this.canvasElement.nativeElement.getContext("2d")
     console.log(context.canvas.width);
     console.log(context.canvas.height);
     context.canvas.width = 600;
     context.canvas.height = 700;
     console.log(context.canvas.width);
     console.log(context.canvas.height);
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer. Unfortunately it does not solve my issue. i probably did not explain my issue good enough. I know the default width/height of an canvas and how to set it. My issue is to **dynamically** read the space the canvas has inside a window (window.height size minus header size.height, window.width minus menu size.width) in order to set it properly afterwards. A detailed denote of my issue can be found here: [link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/dynamically-read-width-height-of-canvas-in-ion-content/173501)